# How to access a graphic that has been added to the stage in Adobe Flash Pro (CS5)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I added a graphic to the stage and I need to access it from actionscript, any idea how to do that?

Comment: http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html

Comment: Note that the above comment was originally an answer, and was converted to a comment, even though it _does_ fundamentally answer your question.  It would be nice if StackOverflow provided a challenge mechanism for such arbitrary action.

Comment: Answers that only consist of a link are not good ones in my opinion. Especially in this case you link to a two pages article with no illustrations when it's possible to answer in just a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your graphic to a MovieClip:

- Click on your graphics
- Press F8
- Click OK
- Click on the newly created MovieClip, then assign an instance name to it in the Properties dialog

You can then access the MovieClip from ActionScript.

**Edit:**

To convert the graphic to a BitmapData, just use the `draw` function:

```
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(yourMc.width, yourMc.height);
bmpData.draw(yourMc);

var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);
addChild(bmp);
```

Comment: but, I need bitmapData out of the graphic, how do I take that out of MovieClip?

Comment: You need to draw your shape to a BitmapData object (see updated answer)

Comment: this whole procedure seems inefficient - creating MovieClip that I do not need and then drawing it to a new BitmapData... but if it must be so, ok - thanks